# How to convert or deserialize byte octets to string in python

Tags: python, string, protobuf-python

[image]

I get a message from rocket mq, it's like the string show in the pic above or the below:

b'\x08\xd2\t\x12\x03Tim\x1a(\x08\x04\x12\x18Test ProtoBuf for Python\x1a\n31.10.2019'

The message from rocket mq also has a similar process show in the pic above, the website can be accessed at https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/googles-protocol-buffers-in-python/

How can I change this kind of byte string into readable string or dict using python

I tried decode using utf-8, but failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `ParseFromString()`?

```py
import todolist_pb2 as TodoList

my_list = TodoList.TodoList()
my_list.ParseFromString(b'\x08\xd2\t\x12\x03Tim\x1a(\x08\x04\x12\x18Test ProtoBuf for Python\x1a\n31.10.2019')
```

If we follow the tutorial, you should have generated this module and have access to this functions that allows you to serialize and deserialize data.

> Each Protocol Buffer class has methods for reading and writing messages using a Protocol Buffer-specific encoding, that encodes messages into binary format. Those two methods are SerializeToString() and ParseFromString().